# DynamoDB DeleteItem apparently not working - no error given

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm using put and get without problems, but when it comes to delete, nothing happens. Here's my code:

```
async function resetUserIdDB(userId) {
  let params = {
    TableName: 'TableName',
    "Key": {
      "userId": {
        "S": userId.toString()
      }
    }
  };
  try {
    const dbResponse = await ddb.deleteItem(params).promise();
    console.log(`dbresponse has params of ${JSON.stringify(params)} and response of ${JSON.stringify(dbResponse)}`);
    if (dbResponse.Item) {
      console.log(`deleted row with userId of ${userId}`);
      return (dbResponse);
    }
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(`user reset failed with ${err}`);
    throw new Error(`failed to reset because of ${err}`);
  }
}
```

The params all look fine, but I just get an empty response, and no error, but no deletion either. I'm using the same .promise() on all my other dynamodb actions.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the item with that Key is not found.

Comment: Good thinking, but that's why I logged out the params, just to check. The UserId matches fully, for case and type. And if I make a "wrong" param, like UserID, then I get an expected error, like "The provided key element does not match the schema".

Comment: can you show the ddb var, dynamodb AWS initialisation !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem. It seems like some of the SDK functions don't actually work unless you pass them a `callback` parameter, even though it's optional. Even a function that does nothing seems to make it work. i.e.

```
const dbResponse = await ddb.deleteItem(params, () => {}).promise();
```

Answer (score 3):

When you delete an element in Dynamodb and nothing happen, it means that the key wasn't found, so double check your key.

The table exist, otherwise you would have had an error saying

> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.model.ResourceNotFoundException:
>   Requested resource not found (Service: AmazonDynamoDB; Status Code:
>   400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID

For example to delete in the table : 
**TABLEXAMPLE** the key : `{id: "client", sortingKey: "TTN-BPLAN-7129-6114"}`

check that the id exists and is correct, also the sorting key exists and is correct

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but the following might help to debug in general:

1. try to remove async/await while testing.
2. remove 'promise()' after call to 'deleteItem' (try to test one thing at a time).
3. do not throw from the catch block, but return err.
4. the "Key" object is in quotes. It may not have to be in quotes just like TableName.

basically, make the code simpler. It will help to debug.